# Replace an expression inside a function

Tags: replacement, interpolation

I want to replace an expression inside a function. Let's say that I have a following function

```
f1 = Interpolation[Table[{x, Exp[x]}, {x, 0, 100}]];
{f1[g[$123, 5]] == 100, f1[h[$123, 5]] == 100} /. {t_[i__] :> t[i][0]}
```

What I expect is {f1[g[$123,5][0], f1[h[$123, 5][0]]}. Instead of that, I get the following result:

```
{InterpolatingFunction[{{0, 100}}, <>][g[$123, 5]] == 100, 
  InterpolatingFunction[{{0, 100}}, <>][h[$123, 5]] == 100}[0]
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
{f1[g[$123, 5]] == 100, f1[h[$123, 5]] == 100} /. t_[i : _[__]] :> t[i[0]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! That's a really elegant way to solve this problem!

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting two problems here:

1. Once you assign to `f1` it will get replaced by the obtained `InterpolatingFunction`. If you want to see the result without the latter in doing your substitution, you need to explicitly prevent that. For example, by temporarily defining a local variable of the same name (by enclosing in `Module[{f1}, (...)]`). A neat trick is to locally redefine `f1` to something that *looks like* `f1` in output, for example a string `"f1"` (see below). **NB:** the best would be not to assign anything `f1` prior to your replacement command at all. Does the first line really need to come first?
2. You want to match parts of both items of the list `{f1[g[$123, 5]] == 100, f1[h[$123, 5]] == 100}` against `t_[i__]` but the list *itself* also satisfies this. For Mathematica,

   ```
   {f1[g[$123, 5]] == 100, f1[h[$123, 5]] == 100}
   ```

   is no different from

   ```
   List[f1[g[$123, 5]] == 100, f1[h[$123, 5]] == 100]
   ```

So even if you do

```
With[{f1 = "f1"}, {f1[g[$123, 5]] == 100, f1[h[$123, 5]] == 100} /. {t_[i__] :> t[i][0]}]
```

it does not produce the desired result:

> `{f1[g[$123, 5]] == 100, f1[h[$123, 5]] == 100}[0]`

You can see that the `[0]` got appended to the *list*. If you are sure of the contents of the list being equalities, I would rather do something like

```
{f1[g[$123, 5]] == 100, f1[h[$123, 5]] == 100} /. {a_ == b_ :> a[0] == b}
```

or (as the above will still suffer from the substitution for `f1`), with the string trick,

```
With[{f1 = "f1"}, {f1[g[$123, 5]] == 100, f1[h[$123, 5]] == 100} /. {a_ == b_ :> a[0] == b}]
```

> `{f1[g[$123, 5]][0] == 100, f1[h[$123, 5]][0] == 100}`